# dynamic grid view loses binding when post back occurs?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

dynamic grid view  loses binding when post back occurs ?

I have a dynamic grid View with template fields  and bound fields as  columns

for the first page load all binding looks fine.values are populated in all columns

when I trigger an event such as selected index changed in Drop downlist present in the column header(inside template field ) the binding are lost and the event is  never catched.

how to retain controls when post back occurs and how to resolve this   problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Everytime there is a postback you will have to rebind your grid. Hope you are doing this?

Comment: i have called my grid creation in page load only is there any other options to retain the grid .

Comment: @Arunachalam store it in a persistent object cache/session/viewstate etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should populate the grid in the Page_Load (which is fired on each update) and set this after populating:   `<gridname>.Databind();`